Condition to guarantee that an inhabited and bounded set of reals has a supremum
This question is about constructive mathematics (without Choice), such as in the internal logic of a topos with natural numbers object, or in IZF.  The “reals” (and the symbol $\mathbb{R}$) refer to the Dedekind real numbers.
Classically, if $S$ is an inhabited ($\exists x\in S.\top$) set of reals that has an upper bound ($\exists x\in\mathbb{R}.\forall y\in S.(y\leq x)$), then it has a supremum (i.e., an upper bound $x$ such that additionally $\forall\delta>0.\exists y\in S.(y\geq x-\delta)$).  Constructively, this can no longer be asserted.
[Edit: also, it is worth noting that “supremum” is a constructively stronger notion than “least upper bound”: see comment by Jean Abou Samra below, and my reply to it.  So, to be clear, I am asking about “supremum”, and this is why I recalled the definition.]
Question: What nice additional conditions can we add to “inhabited” and “bounded above” to guarantee that $S$ has a supremum?  Specifically, can we find one of “topological” nature?
Discussion about locatedness:
One notion relevant here is “locatedness”.  However, there is an entire maze of subtly different notations that go under some variation of this term.
The most standard definition of “locatedness” of $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ seems to be that for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$ the distance $d(z,S)$ exits, but this is not at all topological, and also, since the distance is defined as the infemum of $|z-y|$ for $y\in S$, applying this with $z$ being an upper bound of $S$ does guarantee that $S$ has a supremum…  but in an absolutely trivial way, so something less circular is desirable.
One form of locatedness that I had incorrectly believed to be sufficient (in conjunction with “inhabited” and “bounded above” to guarantee that the set has a supremum), and which [1] calls “pointwise almost located” is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.\forall \delta>0.(&(\exists y\in S.(|x-y|<\delta))\\
\lor\;&(\exists \eta>0.\neg\exists y\in S.(|x-y|<\eta)))
\end{aligned}
\tag{*}
$$
that is, in topological terms,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.\forall U\,\text{open}\ni x.(&S\cap U\;\text{inhabited}\\
\lor\;&(\exists V\,\text{open}\ni x.(S\cap V=\varnothing)))
\end{aligned}
\tag{*}
$$
(In [2], definition 1.2.1(iv) this is called “located”, and naïve me was thus led into believing that what one paper calls “located” might be equivalent to what another paper calls “located”.  Ha, ha, silly me.)
In the latter form, this is the sort of condition I am after.  However, it is not sufficient, as the following counterexample slightly adapted from [1] shows: let $(s_n)$ be a Specker sequence in $[0,1]$, i.e., an increasing sequence of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ that is bounded away from any real (meaning: $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.\exists\eta>0.\exists N.\forall n\geq N.(|x-s_n|\geq\eta)$).  Let $(b_n)$ be a binary sequence at most one term of which equals $1$.  Let $S := \{-1\} \cup \{s_n : b_n=1\}$.  Then $S$ is inhabited (by $-1$), bounded above (by $1$), satisfies (*) (as is easy to see from the property of $(s_n)$), but if it has a supremum $x$ then either $\forall n.(b_n=0)$ (this is implied by $x<0$) or $\exists n.(b_n=1)$ (this is implied by $x>-\frac{1}{2}$).  So if there exists a Specker sequence and if every inhabited bounded above subset of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying (*) has a supremum, then LPO holds; and in the effective topos, a Specker sequence exists and LPO fails, so (*) is not sufficient.
The following condition, which [1] calls “almost located”, however, is sufficient by [1], corollary 5:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\forall \delta>0.\exists \eta>0.\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.(&(\exists y\in S.(|x-y|<\delta))\\
\lor\;&\neg\exists y\in S.(|x-y|<\eta))
\end{aligned}
\tag{†}
$$
But this notion (†) does not appear to be expressible in topological terms as I did for (*): it is a uniform notion and, indeed, [1] expresses it in the context of uniform spaces.
There may be some reason (which escapes me) why we really need some kind of uniformity to express locatedness, but note that I am not demanding locatedness, I am just demanding the existence of a supremum, and maybe locatedness is uselessly strong.
References:

Douglas Bridges, Hajime Ishihara, Ray Mines, Fred Richman, Peter Schuster & Luminiţa Vîţă, “Almost locatedness in uniform spaces”, Czechoslovak Math. J. 57 (2007) 1‒12

Robin J. Grayson, “Concepts of general topology in constructive mathematics and in sheaves. II”, Ann. Math. Logic 23 (1982) 55–98



$x≥x−δ$ at the beginning should be $y≥x-δ$ I think (the stupid StackExchange rules won't let me propose the edit because it's less than 6 characters).

Also, I'm sorry if this is stupid, I'm not familiar at all with constructive reals: is your definition of an upper bound standard? Spontaneously, I'd have picked the "minimum of upper bounds" one: $∀ y ∈ ℝ, (∀ z ∈ S, y ≥ z) ⇔  y ≥ x$.  You require $∀ δ > 0, ∃ y ∈ S, (y ≥ x - δ)$, which looks constructively stronger because of the $∃ y$, right?

@JeanAbouSamra No this is not stupid at all: constructively, “least upper bound” (l.u.b.) and “supremum” need not coincide: “supremum” is the notion I defined, and “l.u.b.” is (as name suggests) the one you wrote. A supremum is necessarily a l.u.b., but the converse may fail, as explained in the beginning of Lubarski & Richman, “Zero Sets of Univariate Polynomials”: let $p$ be a truth value and consider $S := {-1} \cup {0 : p\lor\neg p}$, then $\operatorname{lub} S = 0$ but if $\sup S$ exists then $p\lor\neg p$ (so if every lub is a sup then LEM holds).

(The counterexample in my previous comment suggests that sup is a constructively better notion than lub, but of course it is also a legitimate question whether we can find conditions for lub to exist.)

@JeanAbouSamra: To expand on what @ Gro-Tsen says, the terminology is a bit confusing.  Supremum is pretty standard for the constructively stronger notion.  Some important sources (notably the books Bishop 1967 and Bishop, Bridges 1985) use least upper bound for this same notion; others use it for the constructively weaker notion as @ Gro-Tsen does here.  I agree with @ Gro-Tsen in preferring this — using “least upper bound” to mean anything other than “a least element of the set of upper bounds” is asking for trouble.

Aaha, I was thinking of "least upper bound" and "supremum" as interchangeable. Thank you both for clearing up the confusion.

@Gro-Tsen how do you prove that lub S = 0?

$(\forall z \in S, z \leq y) ⇔ (-1 \leq y \land (p \lor \neg p ⇒ 0 \leq y))$, but (in)equality of real numbers is $\neg\neg$-stable so this is just $0 \leq y$.

I think it's going to be hard to avoid something that isn't arguably a uniform notion or doesn't seem to smuggle in the supremum as an explicit Dedekind real. The best I feel like I can come up with is something similar to the fact that the supremum map is continuous in the Vietoris topology on compact sets, but in some sense this gives the supremum very directly.

The following (somewhat strong) property seems to be sufficient:

For any open sets $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, if $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.\; x \in U \vee x \in V$, then either $S \subseteq U$ or $S \cap V$ is inhabited.

Let's see that this is sufficient. Let $a$ be a given element of $S$ and let $b$ be a given upper bound of $S$. Define the sets $L = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : \exists y \in S.\;x < y\}$ and $R = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : \exists z \in \mathbb{Q}.\; z < x \wedge \forall y \in S.\; y < z\}$. First we need to verify that $(L,R)$ is a Dedekind real (following the definition on nLab here), and then we need to verify that it is the supremum of $S$.

First note that for any rational $a' < a$, we have that $a' \in L$. Moreover, for any rational $b' > b$, we have that $b' \in R$, so $L$ and $R$ are both inhabited.

Suppose that $x \in L$. By definition, this implies that there is a $y \in S$ such that $x < y$. Since $y$ is a Dedekind real, this means we can find an $x' \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x < x' < y$, whereby $x' \in L$.

Suppose that $x \in R$. By definition, this implies that there is a $z \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $z < x$ and $\forall y \in S.\; y < z$. We then have that $x' = \frac{x + z}{2}$ satisfies that $z < x' < x$, whereby $x' \in R$.

Suppose that $x \in L$ and $x' \in R$. We have that there is a $y \in S$ such that $x < y$ and there is a $z \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $z < x'$ and $z > y$. Therefore $x < y < z < x'$.

Finally, we need to use our assumption about $S$ to show the third bullet point in the nLab definition. Suppose that $c < d$ are rational numbers. By the definition of the Dedekind reals, we have that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, either $x \in \left(-\infty,\frac{c+2d}{3}\right)$ or $x \in \left(\frac{2c+d}{3},\infty\right)$. Therefore $U = \left(-\infty,\frac{c+2d}{3}\right)$ and $V = \left(\frac{2c+d}{3},\infty\right)$ is a pair of open sets satisfying the condition on our assumed property of $S$. Applying the assumed property gives that either $S \subseteq U$ or $S \cap V$ is inhabited. If $S \subseteq U$, then $\frac{c+3d}{4}$ witnesses that $d \in R$. If $S \cap V$ is inhabited by some $x$, then we have that $c < x$ and so $c \in L$. (Note that this is the only bullet that actually uses our extra condition.)


Okay so $(L,R)$ is a Dedekind real. Let's call it $x$. We need to argue that $x$ is the supremum of $S$. Since $L$ is the union of the lower cuts of the elements of $S$ and $R$ is contained in the intersection of the upper cuts of the elements of $S$, we clearly have that $x$ is an upper bound of $S$. For any $y \in L$, we have by definition that there is a $z \in S$ such that $y < z$, which is enough to imply the supremum condition. (It should be a general fact that if $S$ has a supremum, then the definitions I gave of $L$ and $R$ specify it.)

I said that this property is strong, although I think it is a relatively natural property one would expect from '(pre-)compact' sets. (Although note of course that classically all sets satisfy this.) For any finite set $X$ and any $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, the image of $X$ under $f$ satisfies this condition. It is also reminiscent of the omniscience property Escardó studied in the JSL paper Infinite sets that Satisfy the Principle of Omniscience in any Variety of Constructive Mathematics. I think some kind of effective compactness should be enough to entail it (although this might need something like Markov's principle, depending on how things are stated). We could weaken the condition to just talk about $U$ of the form $(-\infty,d)$ and $V$ of the form $(c,\infty)$ with rational $c$ and $d$, since this is all we really used in the proof, but this makes it feel a bit more like 'smuggling' in the construction of a Dedekind real directly and less like a 'purely topological' notion.

Congratulations on discovering the (second) modal law linking the universal and existential quantifiers over $S$, although I am worried that this might not work without $S$ being compact. Good luck with discovering the rest of the paper, with which @AndrejBauer was heavily involved, by the way. Maybe after you have scratched your head about it for as we have you will see why it is not written using point-set topology.

@PaulTaylor Thank you for your congratulations. It did occur to me that assuming this condition for sets like $\mathbb{N}$ would probably yield LPO, or something to that effect. This is why I mentioned compactness in my discussion at the end of my answer. In order to avoid this, it seems like one would want to assume this condition in some appropriate local sense, maybe by assuming that $S$ is a countable union of sets with this property in a controlled way. I didn't mention this in my answer because I didn't want to get bogged down in technicality, and Gro-Tsen asked for a 'nice' condition.

@PaulTaylor In any case, Paul, as a personal aside, I'm not really that interested in spending a lot of time thinking about locales and, in all honesty, I become less interested whenever I read one of your vitriolic comments about point-set topology.

The reason why you don't need LPO is that the universal quantifier for a compact space (aka the right adjoint $f_*$ for a proper map) satisfies the dual of the Frobenius law.  This was identified for locales by Japie Vermeulen.

This is, indeed, a fairly natural property that is probably the best we can get, and it is very strong. As you point out, for $S = \mathbb{N}$, it implies LPO. (Proof: consider $(b_n)$ a binary sequence at most one term of which equals $1$, let $I_n$ be the open interval from $n-\frac{3}{4}$ to $n+\frac{3}{4}$ except that $I_0$ starts at $-∞$; let $U$ be the union of the $I_n$ such that $b_n=0$ and $V$ be the union of those for which $b_n=1$; then $\mathbb{R} ⊆ U ∪ V = \bigcup_n I_n$; but if $\mathbb{N} ⊆ U$ then $∀n. b_n=0$ whereas if $\mathbb{N} ∩ V$ is inhabited then $∃n. b_n=1$. ∎)

More annoyingly, I suspect that even for $S = [0,1]$, the property you state is not provable, and indeed fails in the effective topos (and/or in the topos you constructed in your joint with Andrej Bauer on the countable reals), by similarly letting $(I_n)$ be a judicious singular covering of $[0,1]$ (we need one with the property that $[0,1]⊆\bigcup_{n\in E} I_n$ iff $E = \mathbb{N}$). Which does go to argue that Paul Taylor is right in that working with sublocales is nicer. But my question being as it is, your criterion is probably the best we can do.

@Gro-Tsen Still I wonder if the sets studied by Escardó (and closely related sets) have this property, things like ${2^{-n}:n\in\mathbb{N}}$ or its closure.

I believe one can show that if the closure of a set has this property, then the original set has this property, but I'm uncertain of the converse.

I wonder if it holds for $[0,1]$ if we assume the fan theorem for decidable bars?

At least the closure $S$ of ${2^{-n}}$ satisfies your property: indeed, either $0\in U$ or $0\in V$; in the latter case, $S\cap V$ is inhabited, and in the former, there is $n_0$ such that $2^{-n}\in U$ for $n\geq n_0$ so it remains to discriminate between $2^{-n} \in U$ and $2^{-n} \in V$ on the finitely values $0\leq n<n_0$.

There is a topological analogue of locatedness, called overtness.
First let's consider how we obtain the supremum $a$ of $S$ as a Dedekind Cut,
$$ (u\in U) \quad\equiv\quad a< u \quad\equiv\quad \forall x\in S.x< u$$
$$ (d\in D) \quad\equiv\quad d< a \quad\equiv\quad \exists x\in S.d< x.$$
Subsets of the form $U\equiv\{u\|a<u\}$ and $D\equiv\{ d\| d< a\}$ are open,
so to turn this into a constructive logic, we define a calculus of
open predicates.
The atomic open predicates are $\top$, $\bot$ and $x<y$.
We can add $\lor$, $\land$ and certain restricted quantifiers to this calculus:
It was, I think, first observed by Nachbin in the 1950s that
Compact unions of closed subsets are closed and compact intersections of open subsets are open.
For the universal quantifier,  if $\phi(x,y)$ is an open predicate,
so is $\forall x\in K.\phi(x,y)$, when $K$ is compact.
An overt subspace is one that gives rise to an analogous existential quantifier.
However, it's not good trying to define this in terms of points, because any such subspace is trivially overt.
It was done for locales in the early 1980s by Joyal, Tierney and Johnstone. They used the word open, but sublocales with this property have a habit of being closed, so another word is needed.
These ideas were developed in my Lambda Calculus for Real Analysis,
in particular Section 12 considers the supremum (maximum) of an inhabited compact overt subspace.

I'm not sure whether this is supposed to be a comment or whether you are claiming to answer my question.  In the latter case, could you make a mathematically precise statement as to what you are claiming?

@Gro-Tsen. It's an advertisement for my paper, where you can find more detailed and precise answers.

I'm sorry, but does this 87-page document somewhere contain an precise condition that added to the conditions “$S$ is a subset of the Dedekind reals that is inhabited and bounded above” will imply that $S$ has a supremum? (If so, where exactly?) Or are you instead suggesting that I should change my question, e.g., to make it about a sublocale of the locale of reals instead of a subset of the Dedekind reals (or some other kind of modification)? It's fine to suggest an alternative question and/or advertise your paper, but please make it clear whether you are answering the question as stated.

MO is not for general advertising of one's own papers, Paul, but (ideally) providing answers to questions in a reasonably self-contained way. Pointers to the literature should be as precise as is appropriate. Mentioning a specific result in a book but not supplying a chapter, section or page is not as helpful as it could be. If you are conscious that you are not supplying a specific answer or precise pointer, it's best to preface your answer with a disclaimer and some words that might help people, including the asker, why this addresses the question.

@DavidRoberts. In a non-commercial context, "advertise" means "tell you about" or "cite" or "give a reference for". My result is not the same as the Question, but throws light on the relevance of overtness/locatedness, so could lead to a result in the OP's setting.  However, I doubt this can be done clearly if the subspace $S$ is considered as a set of *points".

@PaulTaylor I appreciate you aren't trying to literally sell your paper. But some minimum of words that help people see why your post actually helps to answer the question is always a good idea. Especially if you explicitly say, in response to a "how is this an answer?", something along the lines of "I'm self-promoting my work", rather than addressing the query.

@PaulTaylor Paul, I don't really see what this answer contributes to the conversation aside from giving you another opportunity to complain about people doing math you don't like.
Any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ canonically (and constructively) gives rise to a sublocale of $\mathbb{R}$. Unless the notion of supremum somehow fails to agree on each side of this translation, this means that a characterization in the localic case would also give a characterisation in the point-set case.

On the other hand, your complaint that sets of points are 'trivially overt' doesn't really make sense in the context of the question. If anything, this should mean that the original point-set question is easier to answer than the localic version of the question you seem to be suggesting would be better.
So if we step back for a second, it seems to me that you're saying something to the effect of 'your question is bad because you're asking about point-sets instead of locales; you should ask the (strictly harder) analogous question about locales instead.'

The comment about "people doing math [I] don't like" confirms that this discussion has been entirely ad hominem, giving me no incentive at all for engaging with the OP, who clearly didn't want to engage with me either.  Anyway, it is immediate (but unenlightening) from the definition of locatedness that that is the appropriate condition.

I don't really see how my comment in particular implies anything about the entirety of this conversation. Gro-Tsen and David have nothing to do with me pointing out a pretty consistent pattern of behavior on your part.

@PaulTaylor I want to hear what you have to say, but specifically I'd like to know your answer to the actual question the OP asked: What nice additional conditions can we add to “inhabited” and “bounded above” to guarantee that S has a supremum? Is the sought-after condition overtness? I can't tell from what you write above, and I'm not wholly unfamiliar with the subject matter. If it were my question, your post would not be helpful for me. It's trivial to edit in some clarifying details, even if you want to keep all the context you wrote above.

@DavidRoberts. If you delete all of the Comments on my Answer then I will add the (unenlightening) fact that the Question is merely an instance of locatedess. However,  it is unfortunately not "trivial" to add clarifying details about overtness: I have been struggling for two decades to do this. Currently I'm working on an entirely different topic and need to prepare my talk at CT24 about this.

@Paul I don't see what's so hard to add something like "that condition is overtness", if that is what you mean. It should not eat into your time so much as to impede preparation for CT :-). We don't need clarification about overtness, merely a clarification on if and how the essay actually addresses the plain question. I can tidy everything up later.

@PaulTaylor I don't see what makes you say I don't want to engage with you: I'm interested in what you have to answer, and for the record I didn't participate in downvoting your answer. However, it is unclear to me (as it is, apparently, to others) whether you claim to have an answer to my question as I stated it, or (as your remark that “any such subspace is trivially overt” seems to suggest) an answer to an alternative question which you think is more interesting. Both are fine, but we would just like a clarification! Is “$S$ is overt” a meaningful condition for a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

@Gro-Tsen. I'm sorry for saying you wouldn't engage.

It seems to me that if $p$ is a truth value, the join (considered either as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or as a sublocale of the locale of formal reals) of the open interval $]0,1[$ and the open interval $]0,2[$ if $p$ (so its points are the reals such that $0<x<1$ or ($0<x<2$ and $p$)), is open, so it is overt (even as a locale); and of course it is bounded, and inhabited; yet if it has a supremum then $p\lor\neg p$ holds. So either I misunderstood how overtness works, or overtness alone doesn't answer my question.

@Gro-Tsen If I understand the linked section properly, it shows that subspaces that are both overt and compact have supremums. Each property gives you one side of a cut. Since you aren't considering only compact subspaces, overtness wouldn't be sufficient to use the proof there.
